# Subtract "n" days from a list of format [month, day]

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, python-2.7

I have a this list in the Python.

```
dates= [6,15],[8,24]
```

I want to subtract values from this list. For example `[6,15]` is `[month,day]` so I want to subtract `15` to `10`. I want to get `[6,5]`, well this operation will repeat after that I want to get `[5, 26]` like this. How can I do this code?

Comment: Please share the code your tried. And what do you mean by *"[6,15] is [month,day] so I want to subtract 15 to 10"*. Why you want to subtract 10 if it is day?

Comment: How do you know the number of days in a month without knowing the year?

Comment: Ohhh... probably you mean you want to subtract any random number which denotes the day, and you want corresponding date in [month, day] format. Is that correct? If yes, then take a look at `datetime` module. Instead of creating a `[month, day]`  list, it will be easier for you to perform this using `datetime` object

Comment: Why don't you use a specialized object for dealing with dates, like `datetime` module provides?

Comment: Look at `datetime`, but `date` and `timedelta` will still only work with a year.

Comment: I want to calculate according to the lunar calendar. I want to determine 2018 .So about after 36 years. The date will be again [6,20]

Comment: Don"t post code in a comment. You can [edit] your question and add it in there. Why do you add tags for 2 versions of Python? Do you need a aingle solution that works under both?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour and you will understand [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail and error code... people are more willing to help you so both can learn. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: Complete  usr2564301 request as well by editing your question and remove that particular "code" comment.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the builtin datetime and 3rd-party [dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) modules for this. Note you will need to specify a year, since some years have months of differing lengths (i.e leap years) -`parse` will assume the current year:

```
import datetime.date as dt
from dateutil.parser import parse
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

print(parse('6/15') - relativedelta(days=10))
```

Comment: You may mean `print(parse(...`

Answer (score 0):

You should be using inbuilt [**`datetime.datetime`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) and [**`datetime.timedelta`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) objects to achieve this in simplified way as:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> my_date_list = [6, 15]  # your current list in "[month, day]" format

# create `datetime` object using above values
# since you don't care about year, using 2018 for demonstration. But you need this.
>>> datetime_obj = datetime(month=my_date_list[0], day=my_date_list[1], year=2018)

# timedelta object for the number of days you want the diff
>>> diff = timedelta(days=20)

# New datetime object
>>> new_datetime_obj = datetime_obj - diff
>>> new_datetime_obj
datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 26, 0, 0)

# You desired format list of [month, day]
>>> [new_datetime_obj.month, new_datetime_obj.day]
[5, 26]
```

*PS: You shouldn't be even storing your initial and final list as "[Month, Day]" format. Simply store the list of `datetime` objects, and use it where ever you need.* `new_datetime_obj.month` yields the month and `new_datetime_obj.day` yields the day

**Note:** You must consider about the year in your code. It is necessary in doing your computation and calculating the days. For example, the calculation for February for leap year and non-leap years yields different results.

Comment: Thanks for your help but How can I do without datetime library?

Comment: @Tommy.pillow unfortunately I don't know any simple way to achieve it without any library. What I believe is it is gonna require a lot of code.

Comment: `datetime` is in the standard library, so you don't need to install anything on top of your base python distribution.